# Which guide should I follow to build an app using: Spring Boot (REST)+React+OKTA

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, okta

I was looking at this blog: [Use React and Spring Boot to Build a Simple CRUD App](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/19/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot) to build a webapp (REST based) where the UI will be React, and we will use OKTA for Authentication & Authorization. The backend will be in Spring Boot suite.
While looking at that blog, I found that it uses httpSession to set attribute like this:

```java
request.getSession().setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST", new SimpleSavedRequest(referrer));
```

My question is:
Do we also need to handle http session replication issues if we use multiple instances of the webapp (the server part which uses Spring Boot) ? Please let me know if this is the correct approach to go for or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're using Spring Security with `oauth2Login()`, you will need to replicate your session. If you're just using `oauth2ResourceServer()`, you do not need to replicate because it's stateless.

For session replication, I recommend using [Spring Session with Redis](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session-data-redis).